# K Theory of $C^*$ algebras I, Higson's notes

Tags: operator-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

> Let $B$ be a $C^*$ algebra, and $A(B)$ denote the algebra of bounded continuous functions  from $[1,\infty)$ to $B$. Let $I(B)$ be the ideal of functions which vanish at infinity. Let $Q(B)$ be the quotient $C^*$ algebra.
>
> We have an exact sequence 
>   $$0 \rightarrow I(B) \rightarrow A(B) \rightarrow Q(B) \rightarrow 0$$
>
> Claim: 
>   $$K_0(A(B)) \cong K_0(Q(B))$$

---

I know: from algebraic $K$ theory of rings we have a middle exact sequence, and from homotopy invaraince, that $K_0(I(B)) = 0$.

How does one deduce surjectivity of $K_0(A(B)) \rightarrow K_0(Q(B))$?

I suppose this follows from six-term exact sequence of $C^*$ algebras. I wonder if there is an elementary way to see this.

---

Reference: [Page 47 of Higson's notes](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/higson/Book.pdf).